# JavaScript - detect mobile vendor natively (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, detection, mobile-devices

Is there anyway to get in javascript the mobile vendor?
LG, Samsung Apple.
Is so, is it possible to get the model?
G2, Galaxy S3, Iphone5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try and fetch the User Agent using javascript and see if you can find what you are looking for

```
navigator.userAgent
```

This will give you the user agent.
Once you get the user agent, you can check for some pattern in the user agent for each of the manufacturers device. Generally the UserAgents contains the manufacturer name in them. Also they contain the model number in them.
For example, iPhone have the user agent prefix as **Apple-iPhone4C1/**

You can google and get the list of the user agents for major manufacturers.

For Apple: http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings